# SQL Logic Error or Missing Database with group_concat()

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm  trying to use group_concat to group some rows into one in Android, I get the cursor, but when I request it to move to first position, it crashes with error "SQL Logic Error or Missing Database. If I remove group_concat() it works perfectly...

```
String sql = "SELECT group_concat(column2, '-') FROM myTable GROUP BY column1";

mCursor = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);

if (mCursor != null) {
   mCursor.moveToFirst();
}
```

Am I doing something wrong???

Comment: Try aliasing the GROUP_CONCAT: `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column2, '-') AS cols FROM ...`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't change anything... But thanks anyway!

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this? I am having a similar problem in uwp apps. group by breaks it.